# Form that already being validated by JS. Need to have it also clear fields on submit

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a web form that is part of a CMS, therefore I am not able to alter the input field of the submit button.  The form is already being validated by JS, so I need to add a line to the existing code below that will clear the fields.

Currently, the page redirects to a Thank you page on submit.  I want it to continue doing that. But, currently, if the user hits the back button on their browser, the data is still there.  I need it to submit the data, clear the fields, then redirect to the thank you page.

```
 $('form').submit(function(event)
    {
      if (validateForm())
        return true;

      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: It is unclear how you can clear the fields when you are submitting the form. That means the form will submit nothing to the server since submit happens before the send.

Comment: Did you try adding $('form input').empty(); ?

Comment: I need it to clear the fields AFTER it submits, so that the data is not left in cache.  As it is now, the user can click the back button and all the input data is there.

Comment: Problem is after it submits the page reloads and you have no control over the previous page.

Comment: You can set proper headers to force the page to not be cached.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data.status) {
    $(this).find('input').val('');
    // code to redirect to success page here
}
```

If form is successfully sent, then set the value of all inputs in the sent form to a string with the length of 0.

```
 $('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!validateForm()) {
      return false;
    } else {
      formSubmit($(this));
    }
  }
 );

  function formSubmit(form) {
    var url = form.attr('action');
    var method = form.attr('method');
    var data = form.serialize();
    $.ajax({
          method: method
        , url: url
        , data: data
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        try {
            $(this).find('input').val('');
            // code to redirect to success page here
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
  }
```

FE validation is bad practice in my honest opinion, just good for lowering the amount of HTTP requests to the server. The hard form data validation should happen on the BE.

Comment: How does one know how a form is successfully sent? The form submits the page.

Comment: Make the form AJAX and then on a successful submit, redirect the user to the desired url after nulifying the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `document.querySelector('form').reset()` above the return statement?  In jquery that might just be `$(this).reset()`, I'm not sure.

Comment: And nothing will be sent to the server

Comment: If that is not handled in `validateForm()`.  If it is not, then of course, that request should be sent before the form is reset.

Comment: The OP is submitting a form. There is no Ajax call..... What OP wants to do is not possible.